# Why does this address point to 0x00 instead of 0x25?

Tags: assembly, x86, gdb, endianness

[Stack from GDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qo8yF.png)
This a c program running on an x86, 32bit little-endian machine.

I cannot understand why address 0xffffcff3 maps to the 0x25 byte.

My thinking:
The first byte should be the 0xffffcff0 byte and map to 0x25. I feel like little-endian should not affect this byte addressing, and no matter what the bytes are addressed from 0 to 3 aka from left to right. Or does little endian flip the order of the bytes in the double word when reading? Where am I going wrong?

Much appreciate the help! :)

Comment: Yes, little endian flips the bytes. That is the whole point.

Comment: On read and write, they both get flipped?

Comment: Sure, round trip needs to work.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but what about the addressing, if you look at the picture. it looks like the first byte should be 25 but it is not

Comment: Not sure why you are still confused. Little endian specifically means it starts with the least significant byte which is the `00`. The order of bytes is `00 70 fa 25` (LSB->MSB) starting at address `0xffffcff0`.

Comment: Because in the picture it is being displayed as big endian with 25 being the most significant byte

Comment: Yes, `25` is the most significant byte hence in little endian that comes last (at the highest address) which is why you see it at `0xffffcff3`. Note that the `0x25fa7000` has no endianness, it's the actual value (as a hex number). Could also print things using `x/20wd` in decimal to make it more obvious. Endianness only applies to the bytes.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the explanation. That helps a lot to realize that printing out the address means it is the actual value without endianess.